# Error in deployment of a flask web app with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, web-applications, pycharm

i am new in developing web apps so i might get confused a lot of times!
The problem is this:
I was developing with Pycharm son sort of basic social network, and at first when you sign up the users were created in **local folder as JSON files** and then i look foward to make a deployment, and i did it without problem using **PythonAnywere (PA).** Lets call my .py file "server.py" where i have the whole thing.

Then i started looking for some cloud service and I ended modifying everything in order to work with **Mongodb Atlas** and it was a complete success. I made a lot of local test using Pycharm and everything is OK, the users are now created on cloud service.
My problem is that i would like to make a deployment test with that Mongodb service version, and i was trying to use (PA) again but this time its give me a lot of errors.
Note: i already install all the requirements in (PA) from pip freeze requirements.txt

Is there a problem with PA and MongoDB? is ther any other better option?
Should it run ok if the first version of "server.py" was ok?
I just replaced that file with new one, that was runnning perfect on localhost.

If you need more info just tell me, i am very new in this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide some more information like logs and error messages

Comment: I was trying again, i made two version o server.py, one with local JSON files for users db and another with MongoDB.
The first one works like a charm
When trying to deploy the second one it just keeps charging until at the end it says interal error 500

Comment: I think may be you cant use MongoDB with Pythonanywhere with a free account.

Comment: And if it is the case, what can i do to deploy my flask web app that uses MonogbAtlas

Comment: from error log it says
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members found yet